# Run a script with different input files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, groovy, terminal

I have been using groovy for the past two weeks. I have a script which I would normally run like this:

```
    groovy script input
```

Where input is the name of an input file. However, now I would like to repeat the same for a whole directory of about 100 of those files - is there a way to run this in a single command, as opposed to one after another?

Comment: You would have to change the groovy script to take multiple input files, or does it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use a shell loop:

```
for file in *; do groovy script "$file" > file.out; done
```

This will iterate over all files (and directories) in your current directory. To make it recursive, meaning that it will also look inside subdirectories, use:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*; do groovy script "$file" > file.out; done
```

Finally, to avoid directories (if any), use:

```
for file in *; do [ -f "$file" ] && groovy script "$file" > file.out; done
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this to check it out: for file in *; do wc -l file; done        and it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? It says no such file or directory

Comment: Ha! I thought this was the problem, but I am not experience enough to have figured out the correct syntax myself. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: what if the files are not in my current directory, but in a subdirectory? Saying for fine in ./subdirectory/* doesn't work

Comment: @user132290 it should: `for file in subdir/*; do echo "$file"; done`. Make sure that `subdir` is actually a subdirectory and not a subsubdirectory.

Comment: @user132290 you're running something completely different. Where did java come from? Please join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25266/room-for-terdon-and-user132290) if you want to debug it.